# How to correctly set wait_timeout for MySql server

Tags: mysql-8.0, database-tuning

I have a dedicated server to run a WordPress website.
I use Nignx + php fpm + MySql 8.0.

Php processes are set to run for a maximum of 60 seconds, and mysql is used just to run this website.

I checked the value of wait_timeout and is set to 28800 (8 hours).

WordPress doesn't use persistent connections.

Given the php process duration can I lower wait_timeout value?

I'm tempted to lower this value to 10 seconds but I'm quite newbie and I'm unsure about consequences of doing this.

Can you help me understand better the implications?

Comment: Are you trying to solve some actual problem?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that according to mysqltuner max_connection number was reached, so I started increase max_connection value given that I have enough resources available.
At some point I started noticing that there were more connections opened than users so I started digging into mysql and I stumbled upon wait_timeout.
I had more 300 users connected at the same time on the website, but it's very unlikely that all 300 users make a query at the same time AND that all requests hit the database, I have full page cache in place.
So imho mysql leaves connections opened without real benefits

Comment: I see, then you need to fix the PHP side though, it is not closing the connections properly. Maybe persistent connections are actually enabled and not used or something similar? Otherwise PHP should close the connection automatically at the end of each request.

Comment: No WordPress doesn't use persistent connections, and I can't easily control what happens on WP side because I'd have to check every plugin to know which one is leaving connection open (if any). Interestingly I set  wait_timeout to 10 seconds and the max_connections value lowered. I also started monitoring WP with an APM to make sure everything work as expected.

My thought was the following: if WP tipically serves a page in 1 second, there is no need to keep mysql connection open for more than 10 seconds given that is 10x the time needed to serve the request.

Comment: I agree it should be safe to do and will help with the symptoms. Still I think you should try to fix it - either ask Wordpress or maybe you could add something like "register_shutdown_function" with "mysqli_close" call or similar to see if it really helps.

Comment: IIRC Wordpress can use persistent connections, since it is PHP. Just put "p:" before the connection string and you're done. Performance increase gratis.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille from my understanding persistent connection will avoid overhead created for new connections. Who is in charge between php and mysql to know if a connection can be reused?
php-fpm kill child process after 500 requests served and after a certain idle time so I really don't see the deal in moving to persistent connection. Am I missing something

Comment: @jkavalik I can surely do that, WP provide an hook fired on shutdown. I will also log if the connection is still open just to be sure I'm doing something useful.

Comment: "Who is in charge": Wordpress. "php-fpm kill child process after 500 requests" Is that a default setting? Looks like a waste to me. "Am I missing something" Experience?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille pm.max_requests by default is 0, a different value is suggested if you suspect memory leaks and you want to avoid them. You don't know in advance if application will leak memory.
Persistent connection look good in combination with pm.max_requests set to 0 when you're pretty sure about the application stability.

Comment: I think Wordpress can be trusted, unless you added some custom code or exotic plugins.  In that case, I'd put a high enough pm.max_requests that would allow you enough time to measure memory usage.  "You don't know in advance": I believe a couple of people have used Wordpress before you.  The only problem I had with it, was users forgetting to change login pages and passwords, so their site was hacked a couple of times per day.

Comment: PHP app can't leak memory, each request ends and frees everything. But the PHP (Zend) Engine can leak by not doing that properly and by other things. PHP execution is in most cases one run = one request and the possible leaks in longer running fpm threads can come and go with php updates without changes in the application, thats afaik where the request limit comes from.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille according to this [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31018) persistent connection are not supported by WP.

Comment: @AndreaCardinali strange : https://cloud.accigo.se/blog/azure-app-services-and-wordpress-slow-heres-how-to-fix-it/